# Using the Android Master/Detail flow template in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I'd like to use the Master/Detail flow template supplied in Android Studio for a particular page in my Android application. My application is quite involved so I've made a dummy application to clarify my initial objective.

I want the Master/Detail flow template provided by Android Studio to appear when the user navigates to FragmentC via swiping motion. What is the best way to go about this? Specifically, I'm unsure how to load the template from a fragment in a viewpager. I'm deliberately being vague as I do not want to restrict possible solutions. Thanks in advance.

My dummy application:

**MainActivity.java**

```
   package com.felhr.scrolltabs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    boolean fragmentAVisible = false;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    ViewPager viewPager = null;
    TextView count = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    // test lifecycles
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Log.d("MAIN","get Item is called "+ i);
        if (i==0)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentA();
        }
        if (i==1)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentB();
        }
        if (i==2)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//        Log.d("SWIPE","get count is called");
        return 3;
    }

    // talks to title to give the page
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Tab 1";
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            return "Tab 2";
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            return "Tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
package com.felhr.scrolltabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
package com.felhr.scrolltabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**FragmentC.java**

```
package com.felhr.scrolltabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentC extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager">
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:background="#33B5E5">

        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C3f3f3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTimer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Fragment A"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF5040">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Fragment B"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_c.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCFFB1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Fragment C"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I like  the 'dummy application' :) But why has the main activity that fragment class name?

Comment: I use it all the time before I transfer working code into my project. It has been quite handy. Thanks for finding the typo, mate. Fixed.

Comment: No action so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the effect you're after that you want the final `Fragment` in your `ViewPager` (`Fragment C`) to contain child fragments in a master-detail (Fragments C and D) style? If so, how would that work when the app's in portrait? (i.e. would C and D become separate pages on the `ViewPager`?)

Comment: I solved this and it was quite involved so if anybody wants the code let me know.